# exposed filter item loop

Tags: drupal, twig

I have an exposed filter with an `{{ item }}` loop . It renders the following [actual render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpauf.png)

```
<a href="something.php" class="container label"> Something </a>
```

I want to render it by this way

```
<a href="something.php"> 
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="label"> Something </div> 
  </div> 
</a>
```

here is my twiig template code

```
{% for child in children %}
    {%
  set itemclasses = [
    'project-label',
    'project-term' ~ loop.index,
  ]
%}
   {% set item = attribute(element, child) %}
   {% set item = item|merge ({'#attributes': { 'class': itemclasses }})   %}
    <li>  
        {{ item }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Please, help me,
Thx

Comment: Why is you for loop using `<li>` tags instead of `<div>` tags. It's not clear what you really want to do?

Comment: the `<li> </li>` is for the item loop --- but what i want is to actually break up the `{{item}}` loop render.

Answer (score 0):

solved it after running some `{{kint(item)}}`

this is how i solved it a bit crude tough.

```
<li  >  
  <a href=" {{ item ['#url'] }} ">
    <div class="project-term{{ loop.index }}" >
      <div class="project-label-menu">
        {{ item ['#title'] }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```